# ssh: connect to host port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: ssh

I am getting following error when I connect to the server. Help me to resolve the issue.

```
ssh: connect to host port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Is ssh running on the server? Have you verified it's working previously? Is it your server? Are you on the same network as the server? Can there be firewalls blocking the connection? [Edit] your question with answers to **all** of the above questions please.

Comment: **first:** verify on your server in /etc/ssh/sshd_config if sshd is configured to listen port 22;<br> # What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for<br> Port 22 ---
**second:** verify on /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny if your computer is permitted to access the server;